# C# FTP upload not quite working in Linux environment

Tags: c#, linux, ftp, mono

I'm having issues with uploading a JSON file through FTP

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    client.UploadFile("ftp://domain.com/file.json", "STOR", "file.json");
}
```

On my (windows) computer running it I get an output of (desired)

```
{
    {JSON DATA}
}
```

But on my Ubuntu server with mono I get an output of (un-desired)

```
--------------8d325d822338686
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.json"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{
  {JSON DATA}
}
--------------8d325d822338686--
```

How would I upload the file without all of the details included on the page?

The file to be uploaded does not contain the upload details, as expected - just making clear.

Comment: Somhow the mono implementation fiddled HTTP-protocol related stuff into this upload request as if your were transering some form data, weird. Have you tried using `FtpWebRequest` class (especially with the method set to `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.uploadfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like e.g. in the style used in https://github.com/mono/gert/blob/master/standalone/bug478451/test.cs ?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Works perfectly now, thank you very much

Comment: You can post your working code and accept it as an answer sothat others may profit from this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested by @MaximilianGerhardt to post my answer

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://domain.com/outputlocationfile.json");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("localfile.json");
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx